# Delete column from an Excel table in Outlook body

Tags: vba, outlook

I need to delete a column from an Excel table pasted into a message body.

I need to delete the column in Outlook, not Excel.

I’ve looked and cannot find anything.

Comment: With "column in Outlook" you mean a column in a message body? Maybe the message body responds to the Word object model.

Comment: I am referring to an Excel table that I am pasting in the  message body. I need to delete the column in Outlook, not Excel.

Comment: Maybe you can try recording a macro in which you manually delete the column, then look at the VB commands used and use that for your macro.

Comment: True, but I am not sure how to select the table using Outlook VBA.

Comment: note: the term is `reference the table`, not `select the table`. select implies that you are doing copy/paste function. reference means that you are "pointing" to the object so that you can operate on its properties and on its methods

Answer (score 2):

example code:

you can run the command in the `immediate` window

run with mail item open for editing

```
' this highlights the second column in the second table (that tells you if you have the correct one)
application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.tables(2).Columns(2).select


' this one deletes the third column in the first table
application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.tables(1).Columns(3).delete


' this one operates on a single cell
application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.tables(2).cell(2,2).select
```

this was found by inspecting `application` in the watch window and searching through the object tree